# Google Fonts not appearing properly in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I am using Google Font 'Righteous' and this shows fine on every browser on my Mac and PC. However my client has noticed that on his copy of Google Chrome the font is showing in a very odd fashion, look at the screenshot:

[image]

Does anybody know what could be causing this? Is it a browser issue or is it something that can be rectfied in the code or CSS?

The CSS is pretty basic:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 { font-weight:normal; font-family: 'Righteous', cursive; }
```

As I said, in my version of Chrome it's fine! Any help much appreciated!

Comment: In my google chrome it looks like good.

Comment: It's fine in mine too - that's what I don't understand about the problem. Is it likely to be the other person's computer/browser?

Comment: Sometimes chrome console says:
`nike-filament-capri.html:22 Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/righteous/v2/w5P-SI7QJQSDqB3GziL8XT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff".`

Comment: You are not the only one. It also happend to me :/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the user has a font on his/her system called `Righteous` which is interfering, though I'm not sure how likely that is. And unless I'm blind, you haven't posted a link to it, so I can't really comment much. In response to @kubedan about the chrome console, that doesn't mean anything, just chrome complaining that google isn't sending the right `HTTP Headers` back with the font.

Comment: Ok, the domain is www.boobydoo.co.uk - let me know if you have any further thoughts.

Comment: For the @font-face, Google fonts attempt to use a local reference for the font, before using their actually font file, which enforces my believe the user has a weird font with the same name installed.